# How to avoid slash before hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the [jquery-router-plugin](https://github.com/camme/jquery-router-plugin) and run into a problem.
I've created a Link tag with a hashbang like this:

```
<a href="#!/hello/world">Click</a>
```

and added this route (mainContent is a simple div):

```
$.router.add('/hello/:foo', function(data) {
    $("#mainContent").html("<b>Hello "+data.foo+"!</b>");
});
```

The problem is that the browser calls this (not working):

```
http://{url}/#!/hello/world
```

instead of this (working)

```
http://{url}#!/hello/world
```

How can I get the Browser to use the working URL?

**EDIT 1**:

When I click the link it calls:

> http://localhost/#!/hello/world

But it has to call:

> http://localhost#!/hello/world

Comment: what do you mean by `the browser calls this` ? While clicking a link?

Comment: your `.html()` usage opens you wide to XSS since it uses `eval()`